# How to pass multiple values to keras joined model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm having two pre-trained models. Assume those are model_A and model_B. Here, the model_A is a CNN + LSTM network and model_B is a GCN.

Model_A:

[image]

Model_A requires 1 input as below.

`X_in = Input(shape=(None, 150), name='X_in', dtype=int32)`

Model_B:

[image]

Model_B requires 3 inputs as below.

`X_in = Input(shape=(X_train_B[0].shape[-1], ), name='X_in', dtype=tf.float64)
A_in = Input(shape=(None,), sparse=True, dtype=tf.float64)
I_in = Input(shape=(), name='segment_ids_in', dtype=tf.int32)`

I need to merged these two models by getting the output of the layer before the last layer. Below is how I defined the new model.

```
model_A = load_model('model_A.h5')
model_A = Model(inputs=model_A.inputs, outputs=model_A.layers[-2].output)

model_B = load_model('model_B.h5', custom_objects={'GraphConvSkip': GraphConvSkip, 'MinCutPool': MinCutPool,
                                                'GlobalAvgPool': GlobalAvgPool})
model_B = Model(inputs=model_B.inputs, outputs=model_B.layers[-2].output) 

def final_model():  
    X_in = Input(shape=(X_train_B[0].shape[-1] ), name='X_in', dtype=tf.float64)
    A_in = Input(shape=(None,), sparse=True, dtype=tf.float64)
    I_in = Input(shape=(), name='segment_ids_in', dtype=tf.int32)
    merged = Concatenate(axis=1)([X_in, A_in, I_in])

    concat = concatenate([model_A.output, model_B.output], axis=-1)
    concat = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(concat)

    model = Model(inputs=[model_A.input, merged], outputs=concat)
    adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
    return model

model = final_model()
model.fit([X_train_A,[X_train_B, A_train_B, I_]], [y_train_A], verbose=1)
```

After I executed this code I got below error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-8c7e818acc11> in <module>
----> 1 model = final_model()
      2 
      3 print('Fitting model')
      4 batches = batch_iterator([A_train_B, X_train_B, y_train_B, X_train_A, y_train_A], batch_size=1, epochs=2)
      5 for b in batches:

<ipython-input-53-5c9278e5efb8> in final_model()
      3     A_in = Input(shape=(None,), sparse=True, dtype=tf.float64)
      4     I_in = Input(shape=(), name='segment_ids_in', dtype=tf.int32)
----> 5     merged = Concatenate(axis=1)([X_in, A_in, I_in])
      6 
      7     concat = concatenate([model_A.output, model_B.output], axis=-1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    746           # Build layer if applicable (if the `build` method has been
    747           # overridden).
--> 748           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    749           cast_inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
    750 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _maybe_build(self, inputs)
   2114         # operations.
   2115         with tf_utils.maybe_init_scope(self):
-> 2116           self.build(input_shapes)
   2117       # We must set self.built since user defined build functions are not
   2118       # constrained to set self.built.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py in wrapper(instance, input_shape)
    304     if input_shape is not None:
    305       input_shape = convert_shapes(input_shape, to_tuples=True)
--> 306     output_shape = fn(instance, input_shape)
    307     # Return shapes from `fn` as TensorShapes.
    308     if output_shape is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/merge.py in build(self, input_shape)
    380     shape_set = set()
    381     for i in range(len(reduced_inputs_shapes)):
--> 382       del reduced_inputs_shapes[i][self.axis]
    383       shape_set.add(tuple(reduced_inputs_shapes[i]))
    384 

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Can somebody help me to solve how do I pass these input values to two different models?

**----Edit 01----**

After modifing the code based on Andrea's suggestion I'm getting the following error. I tried to pass inputs using np.array() as well, but still getting the same error. Can you please check where I did the mistake?

Also, here are the values I'm passing to Model B. Since it is a graph, X_ is an `N*d` feature vector, A_ is an `N*N` Adjacency Matrix, I_ is the segment_ids getting by calling to `get('XAI')`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-22f819a7a9cd> in <module>
     18     return model
     19 
---> 20 model = final_model()
     21 print('Fitting model')
     22 batches = batch_iterator([A_train_B, X_train_B, y_train_B, X_train_A, y_train_A], batch_size=1, epochs=2)

<ipython-input-71-22f819a7a9cd> in final_model()
      7 
      8 def final_model():
----> 9     concat = Concatenate(-1)([model_A.outputs, model_B.outputs]) # merge outputs
     10     concat = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(concat)
     11 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    771                     not base_layer_utils.is_in_eager_or_tf_function()):
    772                   with auto_control_deps.AutomaticControlDependencies() as acd:
--> 773                     outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    774                     # Wrap Tensors in `outputs` in `tf.identity` to avoid
    775                     # circular dependencies.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/merge.py in call(self, inputs)
    179         return y
    180     else:
--> 181       return self._merge_function(inputs)
    182 
    183   @tf_utils.shape_type_conversion

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/merge.py in _merge_function(self, inputs)
    402 
    403   def _merge_function(self, inputs):
--> 404     return K.concatenate(inputs, axis=self.axis)
    405 
    406   @tf_utils.shape_type_conversion

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py in concatenate(tensors, axis)
   2671   """
   2672   if axis < 0:
-> 2673     rank = ndim(tensors[0])
   2674     if rank:
   2675       axis %= rank

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py in ndim(x)
   1200 
   1201   """
-> 1202   dims = x.shape._dims
   1203   if dims is not None:
   1204     return len(dims)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below solution to my issue.

```py
# Constructing the model
concat = Concatenate(-1)([model_A.output, model_B.output]) # merge outputs
concat = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(concat)

model = Model(inputs=[model_A.inputs, model_B.inputs], outputs=concat)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',  
              loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Training setup
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
loss_fn = model.loss_functions[0]
acc_fn = lambda x, y: K.mean(tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy(x, y))

# Training function
@tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True)
def train_step(inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(inputs, training=True)
        loss = loss_fn(targets, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    return loss, acc_fn(targets, predictions)

# Training the model
batches = batch_iterator([A_train_B, X_train_B, y_train_B, X_train_A], batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
for b in batches:
    X_, A_, I_ = Batch(b[0], b[1]).get('XAI')
    A_ = sp_matrix_to_sp_tensor(A_)
    y_ = b[2]
    X_A_ = b[3]
    outs = train_step([X_A_, X_, A_, I_], y_)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `I_in = Input(shape=(), name='segment_ids_in', dtype=tf.int32)`, this input layer has a shape of `(None,)` (has a rank of one) while the other inputs have rank two which translates to shapes like `(None, 2)`. You can see this in the model summaries. You are trying to concatenate by the second dimension `(axis=1)` which cannot be done, since `I_in` does not have a second dimension, only the batch dimension.

Try to expand your `I_in` to have a second dimension, eg.:

```
def final_model():  
    X_in = Input(shape=(X_train_B[0].shape[-1] ), name='X_in', dtype=tf.float64)
    A_in = Input(shape=(None,), sparse=True, dtype=tf.float64)
    I_in = Input(shape=(), name='segment_ids_in', dtype=tf.int32)
    I_in = Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, -1))(I_in) 
    merged = Concatenate(axis=1)([X_in, A_in, I_in])

    concat = concatenate([model_A.output, model_B.output], axis=-1)
    concat = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(concat)

    model = Model(inputs=[model_A.input, merged], outputs=concat)
    adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
    return model
```

**Edit after clarification from OP**:

You are not passing the inputs through your model in your code. If I understand you correctly, you have 4 inputs, want to pass the first one through model_A, the rest through model_B. In the end you want to output the second to last layer outputs concatenated. For this, you do not need to concatenate the inputs for model_B. 
Since I do not have your full code, I could not try it, but I think this should work:

```
model_A = load_model('model_A.h5')

model_B = load_model('model_B.h5', custom_objects={'GraphConvSkip': GraphConvSkip, 'MinCutPool': MinCutPool,
                                                'GlobalAvgPool': GlobalAvgPool})

def final_model():
    concat = Concatenate(-1)([model_A.get_layer(-2).output, model_B.get_layer(-2).output]) # merge outputs
    concat = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(concat)

    model = Model(inputs=[model_A.inputs, model_B.inputs], # the inputs do not change!
                  outputs=concat)
    adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, 
                                    epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics= 
                 ['acc'])
    return model

model = final_model()
model.fit([X_train_A, X_train_B, A_train_B, I_], # notice how the inner list disappeared!
          [y_train_A], verbose=1)
```

Make sure, that your `y_train_A` is of shape (BATCH_NUM, 64) since you are concatenating two (BATCH_NUM, 32) tensors by the last axis (the second to last layer outputs).

Comment: Thank you Andrea. I tried what you suggested here. However, I'm unfortunately getting the following error this time. Is it due to changing the input shape of I_? Is there any different approach to pass input to this concatenated model? TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, float32, int32] that don't all match.

Comment: I found that the above-mentioned issue is due to the dtype of the three input values. Because tf.concat() required the same dtype and I_in input is having int32 as dtype. I can't change the dtype of that input since  'segment_ids' has DataType int32 or int64 only. So, is there any other way to pass these inputs to two models?

Comment: Just to clarify: you have 1 input to model_A, you have 3 inputs to model B. You want a new model, with 4 inputs basically, pass these through the models, and concatenate the individual second to last layer outputs?

Comment: After modifing the code based on your suggestion I'm getting another error. I modified the question and under EDIT 01, you will see the error I'm getting now. I tried to pass inputs using np.array() as well, but still getting the same error. Can you please check where I did the mistake? Here to get a quick understanding about my inputs; X_ is a feature vector, A_ is an Adjacency Matrix, I_ is the segment_ids .

Comment: Without being able to run the code, this is going to be a long debugging session. If you can share a github repo, that would be best. Anyway, I modified the second code a bit, give it a try. One of the models (A or B) outputs a list that is causing the error in the Concatenate layer.

Comment: I tried your next suggestion as well. But it didn't work. Please check the full code in GitHub and help me on this matter. GitHub link: https://github.com/sna-hm/sna-dl/blob/master/concat_model.py